# Devise | autogenerated user password does not show up in email sent

Tags: ruby, devise, passwords, auto-generate

I am trying to set up an email where a referrer will fill in some information in a form about a referee. The referee will receive an email to subscribe to my services with 2 different messages depending if he is already existing in the database or not (ghost status). But when the email is sent, the password is not automatically generated. Why ?

Email sent:

```
You have been registered as a teacher on XX.
Please confirm your account

<a href="http://localhost:3000/en/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=6Ac-y5Ymv1GNAkb5whUK">Confirm my account</a>
and connect with these credentials log in:<br /> 
login: bb@ee.fr<br /> 
password:
```

My controller:

```
def new_teacher_registered(teacher, user = nil)
@teacher = teacher
@user = user
@password = user.generate_password
mail(from: 'XX', to: teacher.email, bcc: "YY", subject: 'You have been registered on XYZ')
end
```

My view:

```
<% if @user.ghost? %>
You have been registered as a teacher on XXX.
Please confirm your account

<%= link_to "Confirm my account",
confirmation_url(@user, I18n.locale, :confirmation_token => @user.confirmation_token) %>

and connect with these credentials log in:<br /> 
login: <%= @user.email %> <br /> 
password: <%= @password %>

<%else%>
You have been registered on XX by <%= @teacher.studios.first.user.contact.location.name %>
```

And I have the generate_password method in my User controller

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
.....
def generate_password
 unless self.encrypted_password
  @password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
   if self.update(password: password, password_confirmation: password)
    @password
    else
     false
   end
 end
end
......
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sending them an email with a password (not a best practice), why not send them a link where they can create their own password on your secure site?

The below example will create a reset link for them to click and give them a temporary password so that devise is happy, and then send an email with the link(the raw token).

```
raw_token, hashed_token = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)
self.reset_password_token = hashed_token
self.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
self.password = Devise.friendly_token.first(8)
self.save
UserMailer.add_to_website(course, self, raw_token).deliver_later
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try to look into that direction :)

Comment: @user6877257 if you find this helpful and the solution that you used then you should upvote and mark as complete to show others that this was a useful answer. Thanks!